# How to align a loop with an arrays index

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

I'm trying to wrap my head around how i can use an array that has user inputed data, to create another array that will keep the next arrays data in the correct indexes.

So far the only thing I keep coming up with is writing a loop for that second array that will get user inputs for it and arrange the numbers accordingly with the indexes.

Although, my problem is i can't seem to get this program to compile, as well as efficiently write a loop using doubles that won't be an infinite loop.

I appreciate any and all help! thank you

This is where I am having the problem:

```
//Method 2: What to do with numbers for pay rate
  public static double[] pay (double[] rate, double key) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      double pRate = input.nextDouble();
//Start of loop
      while  (pRate =! 0.0) {

          for (double i = 0; i < rate.length; i++) {
             if (key == rate[i]) 
                return i;
          }
          return rate;
       } 
   }
}
```

Comment: You could make it look cleaner by indenting your code properly (please do so).

Comment: Don't you think there is an extra bracket **`}`** ?

Comment: return statement is missing.

Answer (score 0):

create a class called `Employee`

with these fields

```
double payRate ;
double hoursWorked ;
double regularPay ;
double overtimePay ;
double totalPay ;
```

with a constructor like

```
public Employee  (double payRate ,
double hoursWorked ,
double regularPay ,
double overtimePay ,
double totalPay )
```

Then instead of

```
int empNo[] = new int [holder];
```

have

```
Employee emps[] = new Employee [holder];
```